# How to create a timer (chrono) with NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

This is a regular timer (chrono) with minutes and seconds.
It works fine but is there a way to have the same result with an NSDateFormatter.

```
var min = 0
var sec = 0

func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    let interval = Int(interval)
    let seconds = interval % 60
    let minutes = (interval / 60)
    return String(format: "%2d:%02d",minutes, seconds) 
}

func updateTimer(){
    sec++
    self.timeElapsed.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(Double(sec))
}
```

Here is my attempt :

```
var sec = 0 

func theTime(interval:NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval())
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  }

  func updateTheTime(){
    sec++
    self.newTimer.text = self.theTime(Double(sec))
  }
```

- I'm doing something wrong because it is always 00:00.
- How can I make it work?

Comment: In order to make the timer work I have added the variable sec as a parameter of NSTimeInterval inside the body of the function like this: 
  

  var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(**sec**))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSDate and NSDateFormatter to get time string.
create an object of NSDateFormatter and NSDate, then set the style of your time to NSDateFormmatter, then call stringFromDate to get time string.

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    var date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm-ss"
    dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  // 1
  var startDate: NSDate!
  // 2
  @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
  // 3
  func tick() {
    // 4
    let elapsed = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDate)
    // 5
    let formattedTime = NSDateComponentsFormatter().stringFromTimeInterval(elapsed)
    // 6
    timerLabel.text = formattedTime
  }
  // 7
  @IBAction func startButtonPressed() {
    // 8
    startDate = NSDate()
    // 9
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "tick", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

}
```

Here's what's happening in that Swift code:

1. The `startDate` property will be initialized in `startButtonPressed()`
2. The `timerLabel` will show the output. It is a standard `UILabel`.
3. `tick()` will be called from an NSTimer
4. `elapsed` calculates how much time has transpired since the `startDate`. `NSDate()` is a handy way to get the current date.
5. This is where the magic happens. The `NSDateComponentsFormatter` will output a correctly trimmed `String` for the elapsed time.
6. The `formattedTime` is displayed on the screen
7. `startButtonPressed()` is called when the user taps the Start button.
8. The `startDate` property is set to the current date.
9. An `NSTimer` will call `tick()` every 1 second.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like in practice with:

- four seconds elapsed
- one minute and four seconds elapsed

[image: NSDateComponentsFormatter timer]